# 'TypeError: b is undefined' after upgrading to PrimeFaces 5.1

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm having a WebApplication with PrimeFaces 4.0. Now I want to upgrade to PrimeFaces 5.1. I changed the jar and also updated MyFaces to Version 2.2.5. I'm deploying on Apache Tomcat 7.0.42. Unfortunately I'm running into an error now: TypeError: b is undefined (found with FireBug)
It occurs when selecting a value from a SelectOneMenu which updates another SelectOneMenu on another form within a TabView component. It doesn't appear if I roll back to Version 4.

Here's some code:

*The SelectOneMenu where the selection is made* 
`<p:selectOneMenu id="customersMenu"
            value="#{customerView.selectedCustomer}" style="float:right"
            converter="customerConverter" filter="true"
            filterMatchMode="contains">
            <p:ajax event="change" update=":tabview" process="customersMenu"/>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel=" Kunde auswählen" itemValue="" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{customerView.customers}" var="customer"
               itemLabel="#{customer.name}" itemValue="#{customer}" />
         </p:selectOneMenu>`

*The Tabview which is updated*
`<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/template.xhtml">
      <ui:define name="title">Title</ui:define>
      <ui:define name="content">
         <p:tabView id="tabview"
            activeIndex="#{contentTabView.activeTabIndex}">
            <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{contentTabView.onTabChange}"
               update="@this" />
            <p:tab id="_0" title="Display">
               <ui:include src="WEB-INF/pages/displaymodule.xhtml" />
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab id="_1" title="Sea">
               <ui:include src="WEB-INF/pages/seamodule.xhtml" />
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab id="_2" title="FeedManager">
               <ui:include src="WEB-INF/pages/feedmanager.xhtml" />
            </p:tab>
         </p:tabView>
      </ui:define>
   </ui:composition>`

*And here the SelectOneMenu which is on displaymodule.xhtml and shall be updated*
`<h:outputLabel for="displayCampaigns" value="Kampagne:   "
         style="vertical-align: middle" />
      <p:selectOneMenu id="displayCampaigns"
         value="#{displayModuleView.selectedDisplayCampaign}"
         converter="displayCampaignConverter" filter="true"
         filterMatchMode="contains" style="vertical-align: middle">
         <p:ajax event="change" update="@this, displayTablePanel" />
         <f:selectItem itemLabel="Kampagne auswählen" itemValue="" />
         <f:selectItems value="#{displayModuleView.displayCampaigns}"
            var="displayCampaign" itemLabel="#{displayCampaign.name}"
            itemValue="#{displayCampaign}" />
      </p:selectOneMenu>`

The last menu is not rendered properly and the error message occurs.

I would appreciate any help, I spend some time trying to find a solution without success but really would like to upgrade to PrimeFaces 5.